# PHP/Array : Can't get array value from multi-dimensional

Tags: php, arrays

This is OOP file uploader from https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader. I have an array output like this,

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => news/idENPYygDf.png
        )

    [metas] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => Tue, 21 Feb 2017 03:55:27 +0100
                    [extension] => png
                    [file] => news/idENPYygDf.png
                    [name] => idENPYygDf.png // Can't get this Name
                    [old_name] => lobat.png
                    [replaced] => 
                    [size] => 313342
                    [size2] => 306.00 KB
                    [type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => image
                            [1] => png
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm trying to get the name but seems not working is this correct? I got an error says Notice: Undefined index: name

```
if($data['isComplete']){
     $files = $data['data']['metas']['name'];
     echo'<pre>';
     print_r($files);
     echo'</pre>';

}
```

Comment: `$data['data']['metas'][0]['name'];`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks

Comment: Ahaa...common mistake..You are not passing the index value of the array element..! :D :P

Answer (score 1):

The tag 'name' is inside a position in the 'metas' array, so I'd try with

```
$data['data']['metas'][0]['name'];
```

or with

```
$data['metas'][0]['name'];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: There was no need to post answer...! Already mentioned in the comments..! :D Its just a simple issue..!